# MongoDB Post/ Create only Returning ID :: Possible JSON Formatting Issue

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am currently doing a Full Stack Web Developer Bootcamp course and have been tasked with the creation of my first MERN Stack application using the CRUD operations.

When creating a new item, only the id gets displayed. I have tested this on Postman and it works, but not via the application.

Please see below:

- Postman:

[image]

- Application:

[image]

This is most probably a problem regarding JSON formatting, which I tried to address by adding headers, utilizing stringify and parsing information. I am not too sure where I am going wrong with this.

My code is as follows:

- Server: carsModel.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const carSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  Model: {
    type: String,
  },
  Make: {
    type: String,
  },
  Owner: {
    type: String,
  },
  Registration: {
    type: String,
  },
  Address: {
    type: String,
  },
  previousOwners: {
    type: Array,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Cars", carSchema);
```

- Server: carsController.js:

```
exports.createController = (req, res) => {
  let car = new Car({
    Model: req.body.Model,
    Make: req.body.Make,
    Owner: req.body.Owner,
    Registration: req.body.Registration,
    Address: req.body.Address,
    previousOwners: req.body.previousOwners,
  });
  car
    .save()
    .then((cars) => res.json(cars))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error creating the car." + err));
};
```

- Server: carsRouter.js:

```
router.post("/create", cars.createController);
```

- Server: server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const logger = require("morgan");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const dbConfig = require("./config/db.config.js");
const carRoutes = require("./routes/carsRouter.js");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(helmet());

const uri = `mongodb+srv://${dbConfig.DB_USERNAME}:${dbConfig.DB_PASSWORD}@cluster1.4xta9.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
console.log(
  `mongodb+srv://${dbConfig.DB_USERNAME}:${dbConfig.DB_PASSWORD}@cluster1.4xta9.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
);

mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
console.log(uri);

mongoose.connection.on("error", function () {
  console.log("Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...");
  process.exit();
});

mongoose.connection.once("open", function () {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

app.use("/cars", carRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT);
console.log(
  "Navigate to http://localhost:8080/cars. Server is listening on port",
  PORT
);

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  next(err);
});
```

- Client: carEdit.js:

```
const create = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post("cars/create", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          Model,
          Make,
          Owner,
          Registration,
          Address,
          previousOwners,
        }),
      })
      .then((response) => {
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/success.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Error",
          confirmButtonColor: "#007aff",
          width: 400,
          title: "SUCCESS!",
        });
        setCars(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/exclamation.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Error",
          confirmButtonColor: "#ff0000",
          width: 400,
          title: "ERROR!",
          text: "User data missing",
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      });
  };
```

```
            <Button
              type="button"
              title="Add New Car"
              onClick={(e) => create(e)}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} />
              Add
            </Button>
```

Please see here the link to the GitHub repository: https://github.com/ChanBos/MERN-Cars-Database-Application

Comment: i think you have a problem with your axios request see [request method aliases](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases) for axios.post is axios.post(url, data, config)

Comment: @Daphaz - Thank you so much. That has resolved the issue and has also contributed to resolving other function problems in my application. I greatly appreciate your assistance. Have a lovely day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the assistance offered by @Daphaz, this matter has been resolved.

The code has been amended to exclude the following section, as it is being handled by Axios already:

```
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
```

The final code is as follows:

Client: carEdit.js:

```
const create = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post("cars/create", {
        Model,
        Make,
        Owner,
        Registration,
        Address,
        previousOwners,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/success.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Error",
          confirmButtonColor: "#007aff",
          width: 400,
          title: "SUCCESS!",
        });
        setCars(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/exclamation.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Error",
          confirmButtonColor: "#ff0000",
          width: 400,
          title: "ERROR!",
          text: "User data missing",
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      });
  };
```